# Rails 4 + ActiveAdmin: Attribute limited to a few values -- customizing ActiveAdmin form based on this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So I have a `CareerEntry` model that has a `fullintern` attribute, which is a string that is supposed to specify whether the entry represents an internship or a full-time position. I limit the values that can appear in this attribute as follows:

`validates_inclusion_of :fullintern, :in => ["Internship", "Full-time"]`

However, in ActiveAdmin, the part in the edit form that deals with the `fullintern` attribute still has a text field. How do I make it a dropdown box where the admin can select either "Internship" or "Full-time"?

Thanks.

Comment: You can rewrite apropriate partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Formtastic's input helpers to use a `select` input:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :fullintern, as: :select, collection: ["Internship", "Full-time"]
  end
  f.actions
end
```

See [Formtastic's usage section](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#usage) for the full set of native capabilities.